Quartz Scheduler: High Job Failure Rate at Midnight in Multi-Tenant Database System
I am experiencing a high rate of job failures with my Quartz Scheduler setup in a Spring Boot application. Approximately 3,00,000 jobs are scheduled to execute at midnight, and I believe this is causing significant issues. Below are the details of pom.xml :
# MySQL DataSource Configuration for Connecting to Database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/new_quartz_db?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

## Logging Configuration
logging.file.name=application_info.log
logging.level.root=INFO

# Server Configuration
server.port=9020
server.servlet.context-path=/scheduler

# Use below to connect microservices
workflowService.connection=http://localhost:9010/workflow
schedulerService.connection=http://localhost:9020/scheduler
commonService.connection=http://localhost:9080/commonService
emailService.connection=http://localhost:9030/email
authentication.connection=http://localhost:9000/verifyToken
tokenGeneration.api=http://localhost:9000/authenticateUser


# Scheduler Service System User
scheduler.system.user=komriskApiAdmin

## Quartz Configuration
spring.quartz.job-store-type=jdbc
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=25
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority=7
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck=true
spring.quartz.properties.org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate

## DataSource Configuration
datasourceApi.url=http://localhost:9010/workflow/getDataSource
compliance.source = komrisk_cr
compliance.destination = komrisk_

dlKey=DL-KEY
apiKey=API-KEY
apiKeyValue=1d339a8918bfd92522267f0dd76415f8

#Deployment Type : on premise OR cloud
deployed.company.type = On Premise
deployed.company.id = 6

# Publishing Configuration
publishing.start.time=1
publishing.frequency=3

The system is multi-tenant. We are using MySQL as the database with the JDBC job store for Quartz.
Can anyone please help me with this issue, as everyday lots of jobs are failing.
I tried increasing the tread count to 25 but it's not helping much. We have also seen that CPU is also not getting affected at 12 in the night. Apart from this multitenant setup, we have 4 different servers dedicated for 4 diff clients, in those dedicated servers no issue is happening.
Also no errors during the process, so i am assuming that the jobs at the time of triggering not reaching the executeInternal function only.
Any resolution/suggestion will be helpful.
Thanks.

Too high load? Can you spread the jobs out over the night?

Please edit your questions information - 'Approximately 3,00,000 jobs'  to a number that we can understand for number of jobs being scheduled.

Welcome to SO. Additional DB information request from your Multi-Tenant MySQL server, please.
OS, Version?
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server?
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
From your SSH login root, Text results of:
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES;
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links.
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE,
top -b -n 1  for most active apps,
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage,
ulimit -a       for list of limits,
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count,
df -h  for Used - Free space by device,
df -i  for inode info by device,
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:,
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Could you post 100 lines of your error.log covering a sample of the 'high-job-failure-rate' information you are experiencing?
